# How can I make Python get only Today's created file(s) from my directory using getctime(file) from if statement line

Tags: python, datetime

#[Updated] The updated code works just fine, its supposed to get file(s) named as MAYFLY, a file docx and if its today's created file but after running it, instead of get only that criteria, it grabs together with today's created file without a MAYFLY name on the File from the If statement line.

```
src = r"/storage/emulated/0/Leonce Python Projects"
files =  glob.glob(f"{src}\**\*.docx", recursive=True)
print(files)

dst = r"/storage/emulated/0/A-MAYFLYS"


for file in files:

        print(file)

    ctime = time.strftime("%d %B, %Y", time.strptime(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))))
    
    if file.endswith(".docx") and (to_day == ctime) and "MAYFLY" in file :
        print(f"{to_day} Mayfly File Found & Exists: " + file)
        print("..Copying n Renaming the file into its Destination Folder.")

        dst_file = os.path.join(dst, str("MAYFLY FOR " + ctime + ".docx"))

        if os.path.isfile(dst_file):
            print("File Already Exists, We cannot replace it again.")
        else:

            shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(src, file), dst_file)
```

Comment: Please format the question in a way where the code replicates the problem (as opposed to snippets).  For example, you seem to use the `datetime` and `time` modules interchangably in the code given, so i was unable to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can get the file names in your specified folder.
Then, you must get the time information of today.
At last, you must check whether the time information of each file is within today.

You can use the following code:

```
src = r"./"   # the folder path
import os,glob,time
import datetime as dt
files = os.listdir(src) # files in the specified folder
print(f"Today: {dt.datetime.now().date()}") # Today
tdt=dt.datetime.now().timetuple()
for file in files: # loop for eath file
  if not file.endswith(".docx"): # if or not your requried file type
    continue
  tmp=time.strptime((time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))) # the time information of this file
  if tdt[0]==tmp[0] and tdt[1]==tmp[1] and tdt[2]==tmp[2]:
    print(file)
```

Comment: explain your code

Comment: @ash My code is self-explainable. Which line?

Comment: Sorry, but I got the review task as your answer contains mostly code.

Comment: @ash Ok, I have re-edit my answer. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/16482227/wgy11611 Thanks your code looks more reasonable, but I still can't get passed the same FileNotFoundError error code, it says the system cannot find the file specified: "10 Feb, 2022.xlsx" which is very unrelevant! I don't know where could I possibly have gone wrong ..??

Comment: @DanielLeonce You can use Glob module to find some files of the specified type. Example: import glob; files=glob.glob('*.xlsx')

Comment: @DanielLeonce If you have questions, you can reach out to me with email. My email: horton1314@foxmail.com

Comment: Good, @wgy11611

Comment: @wgy11611 thanks it worked but there is a small part of a glitch, I will email u, shortly with a py attachment. Without forgetting thanx everyone 4ur contributions primo supremo comrades